# Generate all combinations up to X length from List<string> of words

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How would I go about generating a list of all combinations of words up to a certain length from a `List<string>` source?

For example, I have a `List<string>` of 10,600+ words which I need to convert to a `List<List<string>>`, however, the sub list only needs to contain combinations up to and including a given maximum length, for this example, I'll say 3.

I don't care about the order in which the words appear in the sub list. For example, I only need 1 of the following in the list:

```
"laptop", "computer", "reviews" 
"laptop", "reviews", "computer"
"computer", "laptop", "reviews" 
"computer" "reviews", "laptop"
"reviews", "computer", "laptop" 
"reviews", "laptop", "computer"
```

Is it even possible given the large number of combinations I would need to generate?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So every distinct combination from that list of of length 3? Isn't that 1.98446490 x 10^11 combinations (I haven't counted ones of length 1 and 2 as well, which you want by the sounds of it).

Comment: What do you intend to do with the final list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure that you really want to generate such huge list. If you really do, then I suggest you to consider to use [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) for lazy list generation instead of this huge list:

```
static void Main()
{
    var words = new List<string> {"w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7"};

    foreach (var list in Generate(words, 3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    }
}

static IEnumerable<List<string>> Generate(List<string> words, int length, int ix = 0, int[] indexes = null)
{
    indexes = indexes ?? Enumerable.Range(0, length).ToArray();

    if (ix > 0)
        yield return indexes.Take(ix).Select(x => words[x]).ToList();

    if (ix > length)
        yield break;

    if (ix == length)
    {
        yield return indexes.Select(x => words[x]).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int jx = ix > 0 ? indexes[ix-1]+1 : 0; jx < words.Count; jx++)
        {
            indexes[ix] = jx;
            foreach (var list in Generate(words, length, ix + 1, indexes))
                yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it appears to work well. Testing on 3 words ("laptop", "computer", "reviews"), it gave me a second occurrence of "laptop computer reviews". After removing the `if (ix == length)` statement, it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I didn't mess with anything.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i ++)
{
  list1 = new List<string> { list[i] };
  listcombinations.Add(list1);
  for(int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j ++)
  {
    list1 = new List<string> { list[i], list[j] };
    listcombinations.Add(list1);
    for(int k = j + 1; k < list.Count; k ++)
    {
      list1 = new List<string> { list[i], list[j], list[k] };
      listcombinations.Add(list1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will work only for lists of length 3. But this was only an example in the original question. What if you need to generage lists of 10 elements? Such solution would look extreemely quirky.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy The original question didn't mention "for example", it was edited afterwards. And for that case my solution is simple, understandable and doesn't have any performance overheads. Anyway, it is very trivial to convert it to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the problem is mostly to check if a combination of words exists already in the list:

what you can do for that:

```
//generate a dictionary with key hashcode / value list of string
Dictionary<int, List<string>> validCombinations= new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

//generating anyway your combinations (looping through the words)
List<string> combinationToCheck = new List<string>(){"reviews", "laptop", "computer"};

//sort the words
combinationToCheck.Sort();
string combined = String.Join("", combinationToCheck.ToArray());

//calculate a hash
int hashCode = combined.GetHashCode();

//add the combination if the same hash doesnt exist yet
if(!validCombinations.ContainsKey(hashCode))
    validCombinations.Add(hashCode, combinationToCheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<List<string>> GetCombinations()
{

    List<List<string>> mResult= new List<List<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mList.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < mList.Count; k++)
        {
            if (i == k) continue;

            List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();

            tmpList.Add(mList[i]);
            int mCount = 1;
            int j = k;
            while (true)
            {

                if (j >= mList.Count) j = 0;
                if (i != j)
                {

                    tmpList.Add(mList[j]);
                    mCount++;
                }
                j += 1;
                if (mCount >= mList.Count) break;
            }

            mResult.Add(tmpList);
        }

    }
    return mResult;
}
```